# Scope of variables in python decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I'm having a very weird problem in a Python 3 decorator.

If I do this:

```
def rounds(nr_of_rounds):
    def wrapper(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            return nr_of_rounds
        return inner
    return wrapper
```

it works just fine. However, if I do this:

```
def rounds(nr_of_rounds):
    def wrapper(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            lst = []
            while nr_of_rounds > 0:
                lst.append(func(*args, **kwargs))
                nr_of_rounds -= 1
            return max(lst)
        return inner
    return wrapper
```

I get:

```
while nr_of_rounds > 0:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'nr_of_rounds' referenced before assignment
```

In other words, I can use `nr_of_rounds`in the inner function if I use it in a return, but I can't do anything else with it. Why is that?

Comment: This seems possibly hazardous: the first call to the wrapped function will decrement the number of rounds to zero, after which the round count will *always* be zero. Perhaps you want to initialize a local counter instead?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since `nr_of_rounds` is picked up by the **closure**, you can think of it as a "read-only" variable.  If you want to write to it (e.g. to decrement it), you need to tell python explicitly -- In this case, the python3.x `nonlocal` keyword would work.

As a brief explanation, what Cpython does when it encounters a function definition is it looks at the code and decides if all the variables are *local* or *non-local*.  Local variables (by default) are anything that appear on the left-hand side of an assignment statement, loop variables and the input arguments.  Every other name is non-local.  This allows some neat optimizations<sup>1</sup>.  To use a non-local variable the same way you would a local, you need to tell python explicitly either via a `global` or `nonlocal` statement.  When python encounters something that it thinks *should* be a local, but really isn't, you get an `UnboundLocalError`.

<sup><sup>1</sup>The Cpython bytecode generator turns the local names into indices in an array so that local name lookup (the LOAD_FAST bytecode instruction) is as fast as indexing an array plus the normal bytecode overhead.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer; it did solve the issue. What is the difference between a `global` and `nonlocal`? `global` does not seem to work in this case.

Comment: Nope, a global *must* live in the global namespace (e.g. at the module level).  `nonlocal` means it could be either global or picked up via a closure.

Comment: `nonlocal` won't pick up globals.

Comment: @Veedrac -- You're correct, non-local won't pick up globals.  My comment was incorrect.

Comment: We can call `nr_of_rounds` a free variable.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to do the same for variables in enclosing function scopes, but Python 3 introduces a new keyword, "nonlocal" which will act in a similar way to global, but for nested function scopes.
so in your case just use like:
`def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal nr_of_rounds
            lst = []
            while nr_of_rounds > 0:
                lst.append(func(*args, **kwargs))
                nr_of_rounds -= 1
            return max(lst)
        return inner`
For more info [Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)