# Are there different scopes for different types of variables in a decorator? (Python)

Tags: python, scope, closures, python-decorators

I'm having a hard time understanding the scope of variables in python-decorators. I read somewhere that non-local variables are stored as read-only. But somehow dictionaries seem to be an exception.

```
def outer(f):
    def inner():
        print val
        return f()
    val =1
    return inner

def outer2(f):
    def inner2():
        val+=1
        print val
        return f()
    val =1
    return inner2

def outer3(f):
    def inner3():
        d[0]+=1
        print d
        return f()
    d ={0:0}
    return inner3

import doctest

class Test: """
>>> function = lambda : 'Function called'

>>> f1=outer(function)
>>> f1()
1
'Function called'

>>> f2=outer2(function)
>>> f2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in inner2
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'val' referenced before assignment

>>> f3=outer3(function)
>>> f3()
{0: 1}
'Function called'
"""

print (doctest.testmod())
```

Why isn't val in the scope of f2?
Why doesn't a dictionary have the same problem as an integer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scope of variables in python decorator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760593/scope-of-variables-in-python-decorator)

Comment: @Joel -- It's not an _exact_ duplicate, because this question is also about the difference between modifying an object and re-binding an object.

Comment: @Joel I honestly don't know if it's the same. Either way, thanks to both, BrenBarn and Patrick Maupin, for answering. It really helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the nature of an operation like `+=` is determined by the type of target on the left-hand side, so `var += 1` is not the same kind of thing as `var[blah] += 1`.  If the left-hand side is a bare name, this is a variable rebinding.  If it is not, it is not.  In the case of `d[0] += 1`, the `+=` is handled by the dictionary object and does not involve rebinding the name `d`.

Relevant documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).  Note the distinction between the first bullet point, in which the result is simply "the name is bound", and all the other bullet points, in which the result is "the object is asked to...".

Answer (score -1):

I think by "read-only" you mean that you cannot rebind the name to the object in non-local scope (which is true in Python 2).  With your dictionary example, you are not rebinding the name to the object -- you are mutating the dictionary instance -- `d[0] += 1` asks the `d` object itself to retrieve the value associated with a key of 0, and then asks the object to put back the result of the addition.

So what you did with the dict was qualitatively different than what you did with the int, which is why you thought that dictionaries didn't suffer the same problem as ints.  This misunderstanding often arises because dicts are mutable and code can easily change the content of the dict, and programmers easily fall into the trap of thinking they are likewise changing the contents of an integer when they are really rebinding the integer.

Integers are immutable by definition -- you cannot change them -- so in order to "change" an integer variable, you always have to rebind the identifier to a different object.  But if you had rebound the dict, e.g. with code like `d = d.copy()`, you would have seen the same problem.

In Python, the `id` of a variable is its memory address -- different address, different object.  So as you can see here, when you modify an element of a list, you still have the same list object, but when you modify an integer -- you're not really modifying it -- you're getting a different one:

```
>>> x = [0]
>>> id(x), id(x[0])
(3063883308, 138405104)
>>> x[0] += 1
>>> id(x), id(x[0])
(3063883308, 138405120)
```

As BrenBarn points out below and in his answer, I originally misunderstood the full extent of your question because I focused on your initial confusion about why something worked with an item inside a dictionary instance and didn't work when using an int directly.

Inside a function, assignments to bare variables (e.g. not invoking a function like `__setattr__` on an object) are always made to local variables unless they are declared `global` or (in Python 3) `nonlocal`.

Augmented assignments such as `+=` follow the same rules as assignments, except that they naturally require the initial value to first exist before it can be modified.  So when an assignment is made to a variable that has not been declared nonlocal or global, it must be a local variable, and when it doesn't already exist (hasn't already been bound by a previous statement) so that it can be used in the augmented assignment expression, the exception you saw will be raised.  Your failing example can be made to work with Python 3 by adding a `nonlocal` statement:

```
>>> def outer2(f):
...     def inner2():
...         nonlocal val
...         val+=1
...         print(val)
...         return f()
...     val = 1
...     return inner2
... 
>>> function = lambda : 'Function called'
>>> 
>>> print(outer2(function)())
2
Function called
```

Comment: The immutability of the operands is not relevant.  If `x` is a global list, then `x += [0]` inside a function will still raise an UnboundLocalError, even though `x` is mutable.  What matters is whether the target of the assignment is a bare name or not.

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks!  I saw his confusion over dicts vs. ints and stopped reading too soon.